# How to handle different modules in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new ember. My app is not single page app. There are different modules e.g. reporting, management of business objects etc. on the left navigation bar.
I am not sure how to design these modules in ember. Should they be different urls like /reports, /management etc. and there should be seperate Router.map() defined for each of them.
So basically each module become 1-page app. 
I just wanted to cross check whether my thinking is correct or there is some better way of handling this scenario in ember....
Thanks a ton,
:-)

Comment: Are they all on the page at the same time?

Comment: The concept of a single page app is not so much the content is all displayed on the same "view" at the same time but that you don't refresh/reload the page. I would say you have multiple routes (and potentially groups of routes or resources) Have a read through the documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/.

Comment: They are not on the same page. App has a left Navigation bar. When you click on the one link a one page app starts up. Does all of them should be treated as single app.